# Sybase own process with 'SELECT' command cannot be killed (own process)

Tags: sybase, kill, sap-ase, ase

I'm using Sybase ASE 15.0.

I have a process displayed by sp_who
by 'sa' user that it seems to be running an 'INSERT' statement

```
 0      18     running          sa               sa
     hostname                0         master       tempdb
     INSERT                                       0
```

When I try to kill this process I get the following message:

```
1> kill 18
2> go
Msg 6104, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'STADF16', Line 1:
You cannot use KILL to kill your own process.
```

It appears to be my own process but clearly I'm not running an INSERT statement.

Sybase shutdown and restart has been done, and all OS processes had been killed.

What is this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run sp_who it creates a temp table to format the output, so you see your own spid inserting in the temp table (#who1result) via a select into statement in the sp_who output every time you execute it. If you check the SQL of sp_who via sp_helptext you'll see the relevant SQL statements. You can of course create your own version of sp_who and exclude your own process should you wish by checking where spid != @@spid against master..sysprocesses instead.